# Load object into a form

Tags: javascript, extjs

I know how to add a store record into a form.

But now I have an object which is not part of a store.

I loaded it using the helper function

```
var fields = someFormPanel.getForm().getFields();
Ext.each(fields.items,function(field, i) {
    if('name' in field && field.name in obj) field.setValue(obj[field.name]);
});
```

but afterwards I asked myself whether there already is a predefined function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setValues`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-setValues) method from `Ext.form.Basic` object. If you use for your form `Ext.form.Panel` class you can get its underlying `Ext.form.Basic` with [`getForm()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getForm) method.

```
var data = {
    firstName: 'Homer',
    lastName: 'Simpson'
}

var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Form',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'firstName',
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'lastName',
        allowBlank: false
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

form.getForm().setValues(data);
```

Fiddle with example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2op**